# How can I merge two tables using a single query? What is the best approach to accomplish this task?

Tags: workbench

How can I merge two tables using a single query? I have tried using `UNION` for some queries, but it only works for certain situations. What is the best approach to accomplish this task?
Please suggest to resolve this on the same.